# An error associated with lapack installation

Tags: lapack, intel-fortran, intel-mkl

I have a fortran 90 file that I am trying to compile with intel mkl. It has matrix inversion functions invoked in it. The installation procedure was smooth. However, I am getting the following message on compiling the code. Has anyone faced the same problem before?

/home/myusername/intel/oneapi/mkl/2023.0.0/include/lapack.f90(21): error #6218: This statement is positioned incorrectly and/or has syntax errors.

Comment: Could you please share a sample reproducer? It helps us reproduce the issue and help you accordingly.